# How can I set maxTokenizationLineLength in Mmonaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

when i want to set maxTokenizationLineLength in monaco editor ,i find it dosen't work

this is my code

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-test-hsi7q5?file=/index.html)

```
// Hover on each property to see its docs!
const myEditor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value,
    language: "json",
    automaticLayout: true,
    wordWrap:"on",
    maxTokenizationLineLength:100
});
```

it not work ,but when i set maxTokenizationLineLength in vscode setting ,it work well

[image]
[image]

so how i can set   maxTokenizationLineLength  in monaco editor?

I want set maxTokenizationLineLength in monaco editor